# How to Fix AttributeError: module 'botocore.vendored.requests' has no attribute 'Post' Traceback

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to get my LexBot to communicate with Lambda so I followed the process for creating the request, signature and everything needed to do so. 
But I am not sure if I need to import certain things from Python. It fails when I'm about to post the message. The signature is created as well as the auth header.

Please advise guys, Any help will be appreciated!

I've used these articles as guidelines: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html

```
print ('\nBEGIN REQUEST++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
print ('Request URL = ' + endpoint)
print('\n' + authorization_header)
print('\nX-Amz-content-Sha256 header is' + payload_hash)

r = requests.Post ('myendpoint'+ canonical_uri, data=payload, 
headers=headers)
data = r.json()
lex_message = data['message']
print ('' + lex_message)
```

So I assume my problem is coming from this piece of code, N.b I removed my endpoint.

Also not sure what goes into data in request.

Comment: Today I upgrade aws cli and started getting exactly this error. Found your post, but sadly without a solution. Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error but for `GET` using `python3.8`. Support for `GET`/`POST` has already been removed from `botocore.vendored.requests` in `python3.8`.

As a workaround, you can use `python3.7` for your lambda and it will still work for a while. However you will be getting a warring that support for this will be removed on `2020/03/31` as well:

```
DeprecationWarning: You are using the put() function from 'botocore.vendored.requests'.  This dependency was removed from Botocore and will be removed from Lambda after 2020/03/31. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/removing-the-vendored-version-of-requests-from-botocore/. Install the requests package, 'import requests' directly, and use the requests.put() function instead.
```

So there is not much choice as to use `pip` to get `requests` package, or use layer as shown in the link below.

More information can be found in [Upcoming changes to the Python SDK in AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-changes-to-the-python-sdk-in-aws-lambda/)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. How to resolve this even after adding from `botocore.vendored import requests`

Comment: @cloudbud You have to bundle `requests` in your deployment package as explained in the link in my answer.

Comment: How can I use the pip method in my lambda function just add that statement?

Comment: Does that mean I can not use python version 3.8?

Comment: @cloudbud you can use 3.8. Please check the [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-changes-to-the-python-sdk-in-aws-lambda/). I uses `pip install requests -t ./` to install `requests`.

Comment: Can we use `pip install requests -t ./` in lambda also? how can we do that? in my code?

Comment: @cloudbud Unfortunately I'm not aware of such possibility. I think you have to prepare new deployment package with the `request` and update your existing one with new codebase.

Comment: That link states: `Customers using ‘requests’ with these runtimes should package the ‘requests’ module with their function code or as a Lambda layer` but of course as is standard for AWS documentation doesn't actually explain how. Why do Amazon make it deliberately difficult?

Answer (score 4):

In this pull request they recommend not to use the vendored version of requests 
https://github.com/aws-quickstart/taskcat/pull/343 anymore. unfortunately many AWS code examples still use it.

You can use the official 'requests' library (https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) instead by substituting:

```
from botocore.vendored import requests
```

with

```
import requests
```

Comment: @cloudbud do you have resquest library installed?
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install/

Comment: This worked like charm for me. I think it shoudl work 'out of the box' on python 3.7

Comment: This does not work with the Python 3.9 Runtime.  It results in:
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'requests'"

Comment: It appears that you need to install request library first, does anyone know how. If I do it from the command line on AWS, I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example from AWS that shows how to use urllib3 library to achieve the same https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-lambda-function-code-cfnresponsemodule.html

Putting the relevant parts here, in case the link goes stale:

```py
import urllib3
...

http = urllib3.PoolManager()


responseBody = { 'foo': 'bar' }

json_responseBody = json.dumps(responseBody)

headers = { ... }

try:
    response = http.request('PUT', responseUrl, headers=headers, body=json_responseBody)

    print("Status code:", response.status)


except Exception as e:

    handle error
```

P.S. I've tested, the code works out of the box with Python 3.9 Lambda Runtime, with no need to install extra packages

Comment: The AWS quickstart example that I was using was set up for a python 3.6 runtime (support for which is now deprecated by AWS). Making changes based on this answer worked with python 3.10.

Comment: Confirming this solution worked in Python 3.8 on Lambda along with boto3 package